# How to prevent key events from propagating from handsontable after using stopImmediatePropagation?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

My final goal is to to automatically add a column to a handsontable when a user presses right, the cursor being in the rightmost column and remove the rightmost column if it's empty when the user moves left; same for rows.

Below is my code that almost works, but there's one problem: if I don't use `Handsontable.Dom.stopImmediatePropagation(event)`, pressing up deletes bottom column *and* moves selection one column up (which is sort of expected behaviour); but if I use `.stopImmediatePropagation`, pressing up brings me to the right cell (and deletes the bottom row) but also causes scrolling of the page. Isn't `.stopImmediatePropagation` supposed to suppress propagation to the page as well? Is this a bug? Should I use some other method?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cLf9Lnx/1/). My code so far looks like

```
Handsontable.hooks.add('beforeKeyDown',function(event)
{
    var $right = 39, $down = 40, $left = 37, $up = 38,
        selected = this.getSelected(),
        isEditMode = this.getActiveEditor().isOpened();
    if(isEditMode) return;

    // calc dimensions
    var endColNum = selected ? (selected[3]+1) : null,
        colsNum   = this.countCols(),
        isLastCol = endColNum == colsNum,
        endRowNum = selected ? (selected[2]+1) : null,
        rowsNum   = this.countRows(),
        isLastRow = endRowNum == rowsNum,
        i, noData, data = this.getData();

    // handle arrow keys
    if(isLastCol) {
        if(event.which == $right)
            this.alter('insert_col');
        if(event.which == $left) {
            noData = true;
            for(i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
                if(data[i][endColNum-1]) // check cells content
                    noData = false;
            if(noData) {
                this.alter('remove_col');
                Handsontable.Dom.stopImmediatePropagation(event);
            }
        }
    }
    if(isLastRow) {
        if(event.which == $down)
            this.alter('insert_row');
        if(event.which == $up) {
            noData = true;
            for(i = 0; i < colsNum; i++)
                if(data[endRowNum-1][i]) // check cells content
                    noData = false;
            if(noData) {
                this.alter('remove_row');
                Handsontable.Dom.stopImmediatePropagation(event);
            }
        }
    }
},myHandsontable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's the solution proposed [at github](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/4220): after `Handsontable.Dom.stopImmediatePropagation(event);` add `event.preventDefault()` (which I've tried) but don't add any `.preventPropagation`/`.cancelBubble` (which I somewhy haven't tried). The `noData` part now looks like

```
        if(noData) {
            this.alter('remove_col');
            Handsontable.Dom.stopImmediatePropagation(event);
            // don't scroll the page
            if(event.preventDefault)
                event.preventDefault();
        }
```

I've made some more changes, though, so if somebody needs a snippet, here it goes:

```
Handsontable.hooks.add('beforeKeyDown',function(event)
{
    var $right = 39, $down = 40, $left = 37, $up = 38,
        selected = this.getSelected(),
        isEditMode = this.getActiveEditor().isOpened();
    if(isEditMode) return;

    // calc dimensions
    var startRowNum = selected ? (selected[0]+1) : null,
        startColNum = selected ? (selected[1]+1) : null,
        endRowNum   = selected ? (selected[2]+1) : null,
        endColNum   = selected ? (selected[3]+1) : null,
    // endRowNum is not necessarily >= startRowNum, it is where selection /has ended/
        rowsNum = this.countRows(),
        colsNum = this.countCols(),
        isFirstRow  = endRowNum == 0,
        isLastRow   = endRowNum == rowsNum,
        isFirstCol  = endColNum == 0,
        isLastCol   = endColNum == colsNum,
        i, noData, data = this.getData();

    // handle arrow keys
    if(isLastRow) {
        if(event.which == $down)
            this.alter('insert_row');
        if(event.which == $up && !isFirstRow) {
            noData = true;
            for(i = 0; i < colsNum; i++)
                if(data[endRowNum-1][i])
                    noData = false;
            if(noData) {
                this.alter('remove_row');
                Handsontable.Dom.stopImmediatePropagation(event);
                // don't scroll the page
                if(event.preventDefault)
                    event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
    if(isLastCol) {
        if(event.which == $right)
            this.alter('insert_col');
        if(event.which == $left && !isFirstCol) {
            noData = true;
            for(i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
                if(data[i][endColNum-1])
                    noData = false;
            if(noData) {
                this.alter('remove_col');
                Handsontable.Dom.stopImmediatePropagation(event);
                // don't scroll the page
                if(event.preventDefault)
                    event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
});
```